# Singly Linked List (General)

Tags: c++11, stl, singly-linked-list, forward-list

To put things short, I am learning about data structures and started building my own library (for practice). While comparing my implementation to the existing STL one I saw quite some differences. That is, when I insert an element in my singly linked list I push elements to the back of the list, while C++11's forward_list only allows pushing to the front (which actually makes sense, because the insertion has to be of complexity O(1)). My question is, why the books that present the idea of a singly linked list push and pop from back and the STL (which is supposed to be right one) pushes and pops from the front? Is one of the two the correct one, or is it just a matter of preference?

Please don't be harsh on me if the question sounds silly, but I have literally spent days trying to understand this and I didn't manage to find and trustful help online. Thank you very much for taking your time!

Comment: To be able to push to the back, you need to maintain a pointer to the last element - in addition to a pointer to the first element. By only supporting adding at front, `std::forward_list` saves one pointer. Why books prefer an implementation that allows adding to the back, I don't know. Perhaps it's easier to explain to a novice. Or maybe by having to maintain an extra pointer, the problem becomes a bit more difficult and more interesting.

Comment: Ah, well, that makes sense. I have been using the extra pointer indeed. Guess I will change my implementation to use only the head pointer. Thank you very much! :)